# Qt 5.1.1: Application failed to start because platform plugin "windows" is missing

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-studio-2012

---

**Edit:**
Some people started to mark my question as a duplicate. Do not forget that many similar questions existed when I asked this one (see e.g. the list below). However, **none of these answers solved my problem**. After a long search I found **a comment** which had been ignored by all users pointing to the missing lib. Now, many months later, the comment has been changed to an answer. However, when I answered this question by msyself I intended to help other people by directly providing the solution. This should not be forgotten and so far my answer helped a lot of people. Therefore my question is definitely not a duplicate.  **By the way: The accepted answer within the provided link on top does not solve the problem**!

---

Yes, i used the search:

[Failed to load platform plugin "windows". Available platforms are : Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366967/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windows-available-platforms-are-error)

[Deploying Qt C++ Application from Visual Studio qwindows.dll error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368826/deploying-qt-c-application-from-visual-studio-qwindows-dll-error)

[failed to load platform plugin "windows" Available platforms are: windows, minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963881/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windows-available-platforms-are-windows-minim)

However, in my case the problem still persists. I am using Qt 5.1.1 with Visual Studio 2012 and developed my Application on Windows 7 with Qt Creator 2.8.1. Application is compiled in "Release"-mode and can be executed if directly started with Qt Creator.

However, when starting from the "release"-Folder, i get the following message:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "windows".  Available platform plugins are:
>   minimal, offscreen, windows.

Folder structure looks like this:

```
release
+ gui.exe
+ icudt51.dll
+ icuin51.dll
+ icuuc51.dll
+ libGLESv2.dll
+ Qt5Core.dll
+ Qt5Gui.dll
+ Qt5Widgets.dll
+ platforms
```

Platforms is the folder directly copied from **Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\plugins\platforms** including e.g. qwindows.dll. Does not matter if I rename it to "platform" as some other users did. Qt is still not finding the "platform plugin windows", where is my mistake?

Comment: I had similar problem. Windows 8.1 Qt 5.3.1 MinGW 32, dynamic linking. Solved by copying DLL from Qt's folder to ../MyApp/platforms/qwindows.dll. Note: there is no "plugins" dir in path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt5 Static Build yields Failed to load platform plugin "windows"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773789/qt5-static-build-yields-failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windows)

Comment: Sor similar problems, please use the tool `Depends`, which will show you DLL dependencies and problems resulting from them. You can use this tool for static analysis of an exe or dll file, but also use it to show the startup of an application with dynamically loaded DLLs.

Comment: Use windeployQt

Comment: pip install python-qt5 This solved my issue

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Okay, as posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17271172/1458552 without much attention by other users:

The **libEGL.dll** was missing! Even though this has not been reported when trying to start the application (all other *.dlls such as Qt5Gui.dll had been reported).

Comment: Where is libEGL.dll located?

Comment: In my case: Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\bin  (of course depending on your Visual Studio version)

Comment: Ah, I use MinGW, so this is not present in my case, hence my problems using this solution.

Comment: how did you know that the missing dll was libEGL ?

Comment: @user1493046 I managed to reproduce this using *depends* and its profiling mode (F7). After the app has started and shown the error, libEGL.dll appeared in the dependencies list.

Comment: Adding libEGL.dll did not worked. However, setting the following environment variable worked for me:

    QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%QTDIR%\plugins\platforms\

Comment: @arsalank2 libEGL.dll is present in my case and even after setting above mentioned env variable I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 46):

I created a platforms directory next to my exe location and put qwindows.dll inside, but I still received the "Failed to load platform plugin "windows".  Available platforms are: windows" error.

I had copied qwindows.dll from C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\platforms, which is not the right location.  I looked at the debug log from running in Qt Creator and found that my app was looking in C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\plugins\platforms when it ran in the debugger.

When I copied from C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\plugins\platforms, everything worked fine.

Comment: Setting the following environment variable worked for me:

    QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%QTDIR%\plugins\platforms\

Comment: Setting QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH worked for me. Thanks @arsalank2

Answer (score 35):

**Use windeployQT**

The release is likely missing a library/plugin or the library is in the wrong directory and or from the wrong directory.

Qt intended answer: Use [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). see last paragraph for explanation

Manual answer:

Create a folder named "platforms" in the same directory as your application.exe file. Copy and paste the qwindows.dll, found in the /bin of whichever compiler you used to release your application, into the "platforms" folder. Like magic it works. If the .dll is not there check plugins/platforms/ ( with plugins/ being in the same directory as bin/ ) <-- PfunnyGuy's comment.

It seems like a common issue is that the .dll was taken from the wrong compiler bin. Be sure to copy your the qwindows.dll from the same compiler as the one used to release your app.

Qt comes with platform console applications that will add all dependencies (including ones like qwindows.dll and libEGL.dll) into the folder of your deployed executable. This is the intended way to deploy your application, so you do not miss any libraries (which is the main issue with all of these answers). The application for windows is called [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). There is likely a deployment console app for each OS.

Comment: This is what I needed: Note, qwindows.dll is not in bin/ of your Qt platform install, but in plugins/platforms/, with plugins/ being in the same directory as bin/

Comment: Thank you! In summary, the files are: Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll and YourApp.exe in the main directory, and platforms\qwindows.dll and platforms\libEGL.dll in the sub-directory.

Comment: windeployqt is the correct answer. I used it and it copied everything needed next to the .exe. It removes the guesswork of knowing which dll is needed and which isn't

Comment: How to use `windeployqt`: open cmd or powershell, run `windeployqt.exe .\target.exe`.

Answer (score 19):

Setting the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable to %QTDIR%\plugins\platforms\ [worked for me](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/issues/2).

It was also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29563968/109941) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37918282/109941).

Comment: While this answer may get it working on your current machine, it doesn't help others who are trying to deploy their programs to other machines and need to specifically identify which libraries are missing/required.

Comment: on 2017, this worked for me. I won't deploy any application !. With Qt creator just Open\New file or project...\ Qt Widgets Application , then Run and it crashes with the same message. Setting this var help me.

Comment: Just copy the plugins folder somewhere alongside your improvised "distro" and point the env var to it -- should work (no need to use "QTDIR") :)

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this and none of the answers I could find fixed it for me.  
  
My colleauge has Qt (5.6.0) installed on his machine at:
C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\plugins  
I have Qt (5.6.2) installed in the same location.  
I learned from this post:  http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=536, that the Qt5Core.dll has a location to the plugins written to it when Qt is first installed.
Since my colleague's and my Qt directories were the same, but different version of Qt were installed, a different qwindows.dll file is needed.  When I ran an exe deployed by him, it would use my C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll file instead of the one located next to the executable in the .\platforms subfolder.

To get around this, I added the following line of code to the application which seems to force it to look next to the exe for the 'platforms' subfolder before it looks at the path in the Qt5Core.dll.

```
QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(".");
```

I added the above line to the main method before the QApplication call like this:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(".");
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    ...
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me...but note that you might need `qwindowsd.dll` in the `platforms\` directory if you happen to be in a situation such that you are sharing debug builds with your colleagues...

Comment: This one worked for me because the mention of qwindowsd.dll, I was aware that my app was compiled in debug mode, and I did install the Qtxxxd.dll libraries but was using qwindows.dll in the platform folder.

Comment: According to QT docs, `The directory of the application executable (NOT the working directory) is always added followed by ....` that seem to suggest that **addLibraryPath()** is always called with current exe directory as argument. So just putting the qwindows.dll in platforms folder next to exe should fix the issue.

Answer (score 9):

create dir `platforms`  and copy `qwindows.dll` to it, `platforms` and `app.exe` are in the same dir

`cd app_dir
mkdir platforms
xcopy qwindows.dll platforms\qwindows.dll`

Folder structure

`+ app.exe
+ platforms\qwindows.dll`

Comment: It is mentioned in the question that "Platforms is the folder directly copied from Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\plugins\platforms including e.g. qwindows.dll. "

Comment: @parasietje app is looking for `qwindows.dll` in the directory `platforms`. I post this because I have fixed it. Are you doing a test before downvote?

Comment: Your answer does not answer the original question. Your answer suggests something that the original poster has already tried.

Answer (score 6):

I found another solution.  Create qt.conf in the app folder as such:

```
[Paths]
Prefix = .
```

And then copy the plugins folder into the app folder and it works for me.

Comment: Ok, I am in a minGW, CMake, Qt 5.12-environment, where appyling the windeploy-tool is not possible. The platforms-folder was there, but did not work. Replacing it with one from the Qt-lib did not help either. Fixed by using your trick (after copying the folder). Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming from QT version 5.14.0, it took me 2 days to find this piece statment of bug:

> windeployqt does not work for MinGW QTBUG-80763 Will be fixed in
>   5.14.1

https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.14.0_Known_Issues

So be aware. Using windeployqt withMinGW will give the same error stated here.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem while using QT 5.6, Anaconda 4.3.23, python 3.5.2 and pyinstaller 3.3.
I had created a python program with an interface developed using QTcreator, but had to deploy it to other computers, therefore I needed to make an executable, using pyinstaller.

I've found that the problem was solved on my computer if I set the following environment variables:

> QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH:  %QTDIR%\plugins\platforms\
>
> QTDIR: C:\Miniconda3\pkgs\qt-5.6.2-vc14_3\Library

But this solution only worked on my PC that had conda and qt installed in those folders.

To solve this and make the executable work on any computer, I've had to edit the ".spec" (file first generated by pyinstaller) to include the following line:

> datas=[(
>   'C:\Miniconda3\pkgs\qt-5.6.2-vc14_3\Library\plugins\platforms*.dll',
>   'platforms' ),]

This solution is based on the answers of Jim G. and CrippledTable

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was to correct the `PATH` variable. It had Anaconda3\Library\bin as one of the first paths. This directory contains *some* Qt libraries, but not all. Apparently, that is a problem. Moving C:\Programs\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\bin to the front of `PATH` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Most of these answers contain good (correct) info, but in my case, there was still something missing.

My app is built as a library (dll) and called by a non-Qt application.  I used `windeployqt.exe` to set up the Qt dlls, platforms, plugins, etc. in the install directory, but it still couldn't find the platform.  After some experimentation, I realized the application's working directory was set to a different folder.  So, I grabbed the directory in which the dll "lived" using `GetModuleHandleExA` and added that directory to the Qt library path at runtime using

```
QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(<result of GetModuleHandleExA>);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by applying several things.
The first, if it is a program that you did with Qt.

In the folder (in my case) of "C: \ Qt \ Qt5.10.0 \ 5.10.0 \ msvc2017_64 \ plugins" you find other folders, one of them is "platforms". That "platforms" folder is going to be copied next to your .exe executable. Now, if you get the error 0xc000007d is that you did not copy the version that was, since it can be 32bits or 64.

If you continue with the errors is that you lack more libraries. With the "Dependency Walker" program you can detect some of the missing folders. Surely it will indicate to you that you need an NVIDIA .dll, and it tells you the location.

Another way, instead of using "Dependency Walker" is to copy all the .dll from your "C: \ Windows \ System32" folder next to your executable file. Execute your .exe and if everything loads well, so you do not have space occupied in dll libraries that you do not need or use, use the .exe program with all your options and without closing the .exe you do is erase all the .dll that you just copied next to the .exe, so if those .dll are being used by your program, the system will not let you erase, only removing those that are not necessary.

I hope this solution serves you.

Remember that if your operating system is 64 bits, the libraries will be in the System32 folder, and if your operating system is 32 bits, they will also be in the System32 folder. This happens so that there are no compatibility problems with programs that are 32 bits in a 64-bit computer.
The SysWOW64 folder contains the 32-bit files as a backup.

Answer (score 1):

For a MinGW platform and if you are compiling a Debug target by a hand made CMakeLists.txt written ad hoc you need to add the qwindows.dll to the platform dir as well.
The windeployqt executable does its work well but it seems that for some strange reason the CMake build needs the release variant as well.
In summary it will be better to have both the qwindows.dll and qwindowsd.dll in your platform directory.
I did not notice the same strange result when importing the CMake project in QtCreator and then running the build procedure.
Compiling on the command line the CMake project seems to trigger the qwindows.dll dependency either if the correct one for the Debug target is set in place (qwindowsd.dll)

Answer (score 1):

Use this batch file: RunWithQt.bat

```
@echo off
set QTDIR=C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\bin
set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%QTDIR%\plugins\platforms\
start %1
```

- to use it, drag your gui.exe file and drop it on the RunWithQt.bat  in explorer,
- or call `RunWithQt gui.exe` from the command line

Answer (score 1):

If you have Anaconda installed I recomend you to uninstall it and try installing python package from source, i fixed this problem in this way

Answer (score 1):

The application **qtbase/bin/windeployqt.exe** deploys automatically your application. If you start a prompt with envirenmentvariables set correctly, it deploys to the current directory.
You find an example of script:

```
@echo off
set QTDIR=E:\QT\5110\vc2017

set INCLUDE=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include;S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\cppwinrt

set LIB=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\lib\x86;S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x86;

set LIBPATH=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\lib\x86;S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\lib\x86;S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0;C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;

Path=%QTDIR%\qtbase\bin;%PATH%
set VCIDEInstallDir=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\
set VCINSTALLDIR=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\
set VCToolsInstallDir=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\
set VisualStudioVersion=15.0
set VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
set VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
set VS120COMNTOOLS=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\
set VS150COMNTOOLS=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\
set VS80COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\
set VS90COMNTOOLS=c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
set VSINSTALLDIR=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\
set VSSDK110Install=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSSDK\
set VSSDK150INSTALL=S:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VSSDK
set WindowsLibPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References
set WindowsSdkBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\
set WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
set WindowsSDKLibVersion=10.0.14393.0\
set WindowsSdkVerBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.14393.0\
set WindowsSDKVersion=10.0.14393.0\
set WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\
set WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\

mkdir C:\VCProjects\Application\Build\VS2017_QT5_11_32-Release\setup
cd C:\VCProjects\Application\Build\VS2017_QT5_11_32-Release\setup
copy /Y ..\Release\application.exe .
windeployqt application.exe
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say, you wanted to have some [CGAL-Demos](https://www.cgal.org/) portable. So you'd have a folder "CGAL", and in it, 1 subfolder called "lib": all (common) support-dlls for any programs in the CGAL-folder go here. In our example, this would be the [Dll-Download](https://www.cgal.org/demo/4.13/CGAL-demoDLLs.zip): simply unzip into the "lib" directory. The further you scroll down on the [demos-page](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PkgConvexHull3Summary), the more impressive the content. In my case, the [polyhedron-demo](https://www.cgal.org/demo/4.13/polyhedron_3.zip) seemed about right. If this runs on my 10+ yo notebook, I'm impressed. So I created a folder "demo" in the "CGAL"-directory, alongside "lib".
Now create a .cmd-file in that folder. I named mine "Polyhedron.cmd". So we have a directory structure like this:

```
 CGAL - the bag for all the goodies
  lib - all libraries for all CGAL-packages
 demo - all the demos I'm interested in
[...] - certainly some other collections, several apps per folder...
Polyhedron.cmd - and a little script for every Qt-exe to make it truly portable.
```

In this little example, "Polyhedron.cmd" contains the following text:

```
@echo off
set "me=%~dp0"
set PATH=%me%lib
set "QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%me%lib\plugins"
start /b "CGAL Polyhedron Demo" "%me%demo\polyhedron\polyhedron_3.exe"
```

All scripts can be the same apart from the last line, obviously. The only caveat is: the "DOS-Window" stays open for as long as you use the actual program. Close the shell-window, and you kill the *.exe as well. Whereever you copy the "CGAL"-folder, as the weird "%~dp0"-wriggle represents the full path to the *.cmd-file that we started, with trailing "\". So "%me%lib" is always the full path to the actual library ("CGAL\lib" in my case). The next 2 lines tell Qt where its "runtime" files are. This will be at least the file "qwindows.dll" for Windows-Qt programs plus any number of *.dlls. If I remember rightly, the Dll-library (at least when I downloaded it) had a little "bug" since it contains the "platforms"-directory with qwindows.dll in it. So when you open the lib directory, you need to create a folder "plugins" next to "platforms", and then *move* into "plugins". If a Qt-app, *any* Qt-app, doesn't find "qwindows.dll", it cannot find "windows". And it expects it in a directory named "platforms" in the "plugins" directory, which it has to get told by the OS its running on...and if the "QT_PLUGIN_PATH" is not exactly pointing to all the helper-dlls you need, some Qt-programs will still run with no probs. And some complain about missing *.dlls you've never heard off...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error and solved it with a different method than those mentioned in other posts. Hopefully this will help future readers.

**BUILD:**

Windows 10 (64bit)
Minicoda (using python 3.9.4) (pkgs are from conda-forge channel)
pyqt 5.12.3

**My scenario:**

I was building a GUI application for some embedded work. I had two machines that were used for development (same OS and architecture), one had zero internet connection. After packaging up my environment and installing on the offline machine, I ran into the error that you got.

**Solution:**

locate the qt.conf file in your conda environment.
for me: C:\Users\"name"\miniconda3\envs\"env_name"\qt.conf

Make sure the paths are correct. I needed to update the "name" as this was left over from the old machine.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of running a QT5 application in windows 10 ( VS2019).
My error was

..\Debug\Qt5Cored.dll 
Module: 5.14.1
File: kernel\qguiapplication.cpp
Line: 1249

This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. 
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

### Solution

Since I was using QT msvc2017, I copied plugins folders from "C:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\msvc2017\plugins" location to the binary location

it worked.

Then check visual studio output window and identify the dlls loaded from plugin folder and removed unwanted dlls

Answer (score 0):

Setting `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` env variable to `<...>/plugins` directory also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error when Pycharm was trying to run Matplot. The solution that worked for me was setting the Anaconda3\Library\plugins directory (for example: c:\Program files\Anaconda3\Library\plugins) as environment variable "QT_PLUGIN_PATH".
To set that you should go to Control Panel / System / Advanced System Settings / Environment Variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Talking mainly about the Windows platform**

Faced the same issue when trying to debug the app build using the `vcpkg` installed `Qt` library, while having my app build using `cmake`. Had trouble for some hours until found the solution. The simplest way is to do the following:

- in your build folder, find the folder where the final executable is located.
- in that folder, you'll find some `Qt` libraries, like `Qt6Core.dll`.
- pay attention to whether or not the library file has the `d` suffix in its name, i.e. `Qt6Cored.dll` instead of `Qt6Core.dll`
- in the `vcpkg` folder, you have 2 options

  1. `./installed/x64-windows/Qt6/plugins/platforms`
  2. `./installed/x64-windows/debug/Qt6/plugins/platforms`
- if the `d` suffix was present, copy the content of the `../debug/..` folder (otherwise the other one) into the `platforms` folder in the same folder, where your executable and the `Qt` libraries are located (if there's no such folder, create on your own).

You can somehow automate this process. Leaving that task to you. If I do that on my own, will update the answer.

#### Edit

If you are using `CMakeLists` you may want to give this a try. Add the following to your app's `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# assuming your target's name is app

if(WIN32)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET app POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
            ${Qt6_DIR}/../../$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:debug/>Qt6/plugins/platforms/
            $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:app>/platforms/
    )
endif()
```