# Changing QT_PLUGIN_PATH in environment variables causes programs to fail

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am using anaconda 3 and when I turn python scripts to .exe using pyinstaller they failed to open and I got an error message that said,

**Application can't start because could not find or load Qt platform plugin "windows" in " "**

I looked on stack overflow and found a solution for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994485/error-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-while-using-matplo), and it solved my problem. However, now when I download other programs from the internet and try to open them they display the same error,

**Application can't start because could not find or load Qt platform plugin "windows" in " "**

I have delete the QT_PLUGIN_PATH from the environment variables in order to make the program that I installed work, but when I do that my .exe fails to open and I have to add the QT_PLUGIN_PATH again to make the .exe work.

Is there a way to make both my .exe and installed programs work without having to add and delete the QT_PLUGIN_PATH from the environment variables every time?

In environment variables I have,

**QT_PLUGIN_PATH="C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\plugins"**

Comment: You could also create a batch file to start and have:
QT_PLUGIN_PATH="C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\plugins" yourapp.exe
That is, just separated by space.
It works but is probably not convenient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I found that deleting the QT_PLUGIN_PATH from the environment variables and adding the platforms folder in my .exe folder fixes the problem. In my case, I am using anaconda 3, so I deleted QT_PLUGIN_PATH from the environment variables and then I copied the platforms folder from this directory, **C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\plugins\platforms** and pasted it to the same folder where my .exe is, which is in my desktop. Doing this fixed all my issues. I hope my solution helps you.