# This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: python, macos, qt, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am stuck trying to run a very simple Python script, getting this error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

zsh: abort      python3 mypuppy1.py
```

The script code is:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('00-puppy.jpg')
while True:
    cv2.imshow('Puppy',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However this Notebook code works in JupyterLab:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('00-puppy.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Puppy', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I am on macOS, using Anaconda and JupyterLab. I would appreciate any help with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem. If you run `brew info qt` you can see where it is installed and the version. I think the problem is python isn't looking for it in the right location so an environment variable must be set.

Comment: I had to reinstall QT via https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer to a directory in my `Users/` path and it now works.

Comment: Installing `opencv-python-headless` instead of `opencv-python` solved the same issue I had on my Mac (I just did `pip install opencv-python-headless`).  I think it is worthwhile to try.

Comment: I solved my same problem by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55617809.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For me, it worked by using a `opencv-python` version prior to `4.2` version that just got released. The new version (`4.2.0.32`) released on Feb 2, 2020 seems to have caused this breaking change and probably expects to find Qt at a specific location (`Users/` directory) as pointed by other answers.

You can try either manually installed from qt.io as suggested and making sure you get a `.qt` directory under yours `Users` directory, or you can use version `4.1.2.30`, which works like charm without doing anything else.

It works for opencv-contrib-python too.

Answer (score 38):

Try installing

```
pip3 install opencv-python==4.1.2.30
```

Comment: This version of opencv is no longer available

Answer (score 34):

For Ubuntu users,

`sudo apt-get install qt5-default` fixes the issue.

(I'm using OpenCV 4.4)

Comment: "Package qt5-default is not available, but is referred to by another package."

Comment: This does not fix the issue for me.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04 when I met a problem with networkx and matplotlib

Comment: This works for WSL  Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11):

This can be solved installing `python-opencv-headless` instead of `python-opencv`

Comment: It's `opencv-python-headless`

Comment: it does not work and gives me this error: `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /tmp/pip-req-build-5wrl9sz4/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:679: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'`

Comment: @FranvaI I have gotten the exact same errror. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here. No answer, but it's appearing in a similar setup. I've tried throwing many solutions at it:

- Installing QT from brew,
- Reinstalling from: qt.io/download-qt-installer
- Installing from pip (using virtual environments)
- Explicitly setting changing the environment variables

  - QT_PLUGIN_PATH="/Users/halopend/.qt/5.14.1/clang_64/plugins/"
  - QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH="/Users/halopend/.qt/5.14.1/clang_64/plugins/platforms/"

Sometimes the issue appeared to be opencv having qt included within it which classed with an externally defined qt, but I'm not sure.

Anyway, not sure if that will help you, but at least you have a few ideas of where to look.

Comment: using ``` pip install --upgrade pyqt5_tools``` resolve the problem for me

Comment: The comment above

using ``` pip install --upgrade pyqt5_tools``` resolve the problem for me

worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

In my case the solution from
 [this link](https://github.com/NVlabs/instant-ngp/discussions/300) 
worked.

```
 export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

Comment: It stopped to complain, but no window appears anywhere...
Wait:  doing back export QT_QPA_PLATFORM= 
starated to work

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue. I agree with Simran Singh. This issue comes from the recent update.

Quote from pacjin79 on Github:"If you are on a mac, make sure you install `opencv-python-headless` instead of `opencv-python` to avoid these errors." 
[link](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/1041)

I personally solved the issue by doing so. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Through many trial and error, for me it works for uninstalling and installing `numpy` and `opencv`.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue with PyQt5 and solving it by using `PyQt6==6.3.1` and `opencv-python==4.6.0.66`.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Turns out in my case, python 3.9 was causing this conflict.
I managed to solve this by creating a new environment with python 3.8.

commands:

```bash
conda create -n myenv python=3.8.0
conda activate myenv
pip3 install opencv-python==4.2.0.34
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenCv changes the environment variable 'QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH' when you import it.

If you would change it back to what it should be using this:

```
import os
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = r'path/to/qt/plugins/platforms'
```

It would solve the issue.

You can get the path of your PyQt directory using the following command:

```
import os
import PyQt5
print(os.path.dirname(PyQt5.__file__))
```

Answer (score 1):

the command below works for me, when I installed freesurfer and failed to launch it. ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error after installing xrdp.  The issue was solved after uninstalling xrdp and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

For opencv-python,

Machines having no display/graphical output (docker containers too), using functions like

```
cv2.imshow
```

or

```
cv2.namedWindow
```

Causes this issue. Make sure to **remove these lines from your code**.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this error message trying to use PyQt6.

### Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:okirby/qt6-backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev
```

I additionally needed `libxcb-cursor0`

### Ubuntu 21.04+

```
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev
```