# opencv: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: python, visual-studio, qt, opencv, python-venv

I installed opencv-python on ubuntu wsl, after setting up a venv using virtualenvwrapper (I use wsl in visual studio code).
When running this code (which appears in one of the articles of [this OCR guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/):

```
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True)
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
cv2.imshow("I", image)
```

with this command on teminal:

```
python script.py --image temp.png
```

I get:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/ben123/.local/bin/.virtualenvs/ocr_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
```

The interpreter in vscode is the correct one (the one of the venv), and when I type  `pip list` I get

```
Package       Version
------------- --------
numpy         1.22.2
opencv-python 4.5.5.62
pip           22.0.3
setuptools    60.6.0
wheel         0.37.1
```

Would appreciate any help at this point, since I spent so much time and didn't get nowhere.

Things I tried:

1. following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/) guide to install it. Gave the same error.
2. following an older guide from this site, was much more complicated and didn't work as well.
3. uninstalling opencv-python and installing opencv-python again/ opencv-python-contrib/ opencv-python-headless/ opencv-python-contrib-headless (only one of them at a time)
4. following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60042568/this-application-failed-to-start-because-no-qt-platform-plugin-could-be-initiali) thread because it has similar problem
5. literally reset my wsl several times just to make sure I don't have multiple pythons/ opencv versions that mess this up.
6. tried installing (to a wsl venv) opencv directly with [the official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)
7. Tried to give up on wsl completely and install opencv using anaconda but even that didn't work.

Comment: Since nothing worked I just switched `imshow` with `imwrite` so I can see the result that way

Answer (score 14):

I had the same error in a completely different context.

Found that the problem was a PyQt5 installation in my virtual environment.
Check if you have a PyQt in the path

> /home/ben123/.local/bin/.virtualenvs/ocr_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/

if so, remove it

```
$ pip uninstall <PyQT package installed>
```

example:

```
$ pip uninstall PyQt5
```

Then reinstall opencv-python

```
$ pip uninstall opencv-python
$ pip install opencv-python
```

Hope that works!

Comment: Couldn't find it in the dir: PIL, pip, Pillow-9.0.1.dist-info, pip-22.0.3.dist-info, Pillow.libs, pip-22.0.3.virtualenv, __pycache__, pkg_resources, _distutils_hack, pycodestyle-2.8.0.dist-info, _virtualenv.pth, pycodestyle.py, _virtualenv.py, pytesseract, autopep8-1.6.0.dist-info, pytesseract-0.3.8.dist-info, autopep8.py, setuptools, cv2, setuptools-60.6.0.dist-info, distutils-precedence.pth, setuptools-60.6.0.virtualenv, numpy, toml, numpy-1.22.2.dist-info, toml-0.10.2.dist-info, numpy.libs, opencv_contrib_python_headless-4.5.5.62.dist-info, opencv_contrib_python_headless.libs and wheel

Comment: Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Can you post the content of the "site_packages" dir or the output of "pip freeze"? There must be something there trying to use Qt and crashing. We need to reinstall that.

Comment: pip freeze: autopep8==1.6.0
numpy==1.22.2
opencv-contrib-python-headless==4.5.5.62
Pillow==9.0.1
pycodestyle==2.8.0
pytesseract==0.3.8
toml==0.10.2

Comment: Make sure not to install PyQt5. Run the code after installing opencv-python. There is no need to install PyQt5 again.

Comment: It's working, but why PyQt5 can't be installed in virtual environment?

Answer (score 7):

Uninstalling opencv and installing similar headless version worked for me.

```
$ pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Comment: Uninstalling `PyQt5` and reinstalling `opencv-python` did the trick for me, as I require the graphical parts of opencv.

Answer (score 1):

To display graphical information about wsl, you should configure x11 related content.
eg: You can use MobaXterm for graphical display.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `cv2.imshow` from your code. Your OS is without graphics and can't display image

Comment: He is trying to make it work so I don't think deleting code is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a miniconda virtual environment, here is how I did it:

First, I uninstalled opencv:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Then, I checked if I could find PyQt files in this path :

> ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/

I found these:

- PyQt5
- PyQt5_sip-12.11.0-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg
- PyQt5_sip.pth

Which I removed using the `rm -r <file name>` command (because for some reason I could not do that using pip or conda).

After that, I reinstalled opencv-python:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an `opencv` dependency issue with `pyQt5`. `pyQt5` doesn't support `opencv-contrib-python` fully. I was building app with `mediapipe`, `opencv` and `pyQt5` module and struggled with issue for days. I found that this dependency problem can't be solved fully with just uninstalling `opencv-contrib-python` and installing `opencv-python-headless`. This and all other solutions that I found regarding this issue is just a temporary fix and don't go well if you want to deploy the app or script on a new machine.

I found the best solution is to use `pyQt6`. `pyQt6` supports `opencv-contrib-python` fully. So, just uninstall everything of `pyQt5` and install `pyQt6`.