trying to use GUI in WSL2: qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" even though it is found
Trying to start on opencv, but nothing worked. I have tried almost every single link available
I tried using opencv-python-headless, opencv-python, opencv-contrib-python
Here's what I have:
NOTE: the python download I'll explain a bit more on what I have done
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
numpy                  2.1.1
opencv-python-headless 4.10.0.84
pip                    22.0.2
setuptools             59.6.0

Here's the version of python I am using: Python 3.10.12.
I am running everything in a virtual environment
I also use the latest version of everything.
When I use opencv-python, opencv-contrib-python, it gives this error:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb",....,

even though it is found
when I use opencv-python-headless, it gives me this error:
cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.10.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1284: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvNamedWindow'

After some research, I think it is because opencv-python-headless don't support GUI, which I need for this tutorial. I'll talk more about it in what I have tried
So, I believe I can not use opencv-python-headless, because it doesn't work with the tutorial I am on.
BUT IF I AM WRONG PLEASE CORRECT ME
So I started with opencv-python
and followed these links:
text
text
I tried uninstalling opencv-python and reinstalling, but it doesn't work, so I moved on to opencv-python-headless and got another error (READ the detail for the error message)
so, I use these links:
text
text
THEY TOLD ME TO UNINSTALL opencv-python-headless and reinstall opencv-python, unintall it and install it again
So, I am back to square one.
So, I did more research and come with this link from a Chinese website (so translate it first)
text
It told me to install opencv-contrib-python
I found a reddit link that told me the same thing
text
NOTE: I did all when I still have my opencv-python-headless, so the error message is different
NOTE: I tried a lot of other links, but these are the most "helpful" ones
And I am back to square one after 7 hours. Pls help

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

obviously the headless package can't do GUI, so that's pointless to try. please remove that from the question. -- have you researched your problem? this site has a search function. [tour], [ask]

This question is similar to: "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm going to need to see the results of these three terminal commands: which -a python, which -a python3, pip3 list

an answer for "xcb" related to opencv: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088095/opencv-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-though-it-was-fou

I have followed the 2 links you send to me. I have done a little bit more research. I think my WSL is not supporting graphical interface for some reason.
I also run the commands you told me to:
which -a python:
/mnt/c/Users/jacki/Documents/mFly/cv-starter-projects/env/bin/python
/mnt/c/Users/jacki/Documents/mFly/cv-starter-projects/env/bin/python
which -a python3:
/mnt/c/Users/jacki/Documents/mFly/cv-starter-projects/env/bin/python3
/mnt/c/Users/jacki/Documents/mFly/cv-starter-projects/env/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/bin/python3

pip3 list:
numpy         2.1.1
opencv-python 4.10.0.84
pip           22.0.2
setuptools    59.6.0

@ChristophRackwitz I fixed it. My WSL doesn't support GUI and I have to update it

great to hear that you found a solution! the which and pip list commands tell me that your environment looks fine (a single opencv package, just one python virtual environment). -- you can run python and opencv natively on your windows host. I understand there might be reasons to continue in the WSL environment, such as other libraries having better support in the WSL environment. however, most libraries should work best on the host system.

@JackieLin For future reference, even though you did wrote about WSL in the title and tags, that important aspect could be not be as immediate as you may believe: many of us open many tabs directly from the question list page based on a quick read from the title and summary, and then begin to review the questions, possibly reading the title again only superficially. Extremely relevant environment info (as using WSL is) should always be reported in a very specific and highlighted section of the post (normally, the beginning or the end, unless the problem is about different env cases).

@JackieLin This is quite important for long posts, as questions should be easy to read. And that's exactly your case: with all due respect, your post is a disordered/unsorted list of explanations and attempts without any clear text hierarchy, meaning that even before being able to understand the problem, we have to understand the question. Links should also be properly named, instead of just using "text" for all of them (which forces us to either hover or open them). Please always take your time to write questions: only you know about your problem, make it easy to us to understand it.

@musicamante I added the "WSL" piece of info to the title and tags. we only learned about that when he revealed that in the comments.

I finally fixed the issue.
NOTE: I am not very tech savy, so some stuff I said might not make sense
So, the WSL I have do not support GUI, so it never ran. I have to update it.
here's how I did it:
I followed this youtube link: https://youtu.be/7Sym3uL6YWo?si=3KT91SulMcEDgngX
when you get to the step: xeyes, it won't display
so, I did this:

close the terminal

open up a new terminal

run wsl --update

relaunch ubuntu

test again with xeyes


if the eyes popped up, the issue is fixed
