# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" even though it was found

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-creator

I`m desperating since days, since I tried anything I found on the web since nearly 1 week now.
I want to use the QtCreator 6.2.3 for making GUI designs in Python language, so I use the python-project options.
Everytime I try to run any .py-file (especially for converting the .ui-data in the project to a .py-file for my RaspberryPi later on) I get this error:

**qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: direct2d, minimal, offscreen, windows.**

What I already tried:

- [How to fix "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows" while using Matplotlib in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994485/how-to-fix-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-while-using-m)
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/90293/could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-in/8
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUmS6XhuPLI
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/58499/solved-problems-with-setting-paths-to-libs-and-plugins-in-qt-app-s-executable-file/3
- [Qt 5.1.1: Application failed to start because platform plugin "windows" is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495620/qt-5-1-1-application-failed-to-start-because-platform-plugin-windows-is-missi)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFHPOZoqzcg

The problem is: There are several directories with those .dll's and I don't know how/where I should use the deployment-tool, or where should I take the .dll's from and put them in.

Here is what I got from listDLLs.exe after the problem.

```html
Command line: E:\Programme\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\\qtcreator_processlauncher  \\.\pipe\C:/Users/LucaGraebenteich/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-OQkBfq/launcher-6256

Base                Size      Path
0x0000000058120000  0x34000   E:\Programme\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator_processlauncher.exe
0x0000000097f50000  0x1f5000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000097e50000  0xbe000   C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x0000000095bf0000  0x2c9000  C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x0000000097390000  0x1a1000  C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x0000000095670000  0x22000   C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x0000000097260000  0x2b000   C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x0000000061550000  0x15d000  E:\Programme\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Qt6Network.dll
0x000000005ee50000  0x53f000  E:\Programme\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Qt6Core.dll
0x0000000095940000  0x10b000  C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x0000000095b50000  0x9d000   C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x0000000095a50000  0x100000  C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x0000000096180000  0xac000   C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x0000000095fa0000  0x9e000   C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00000000971d0000  0x6b000   C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x0000000096800000  0x9b000   C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x000000003ed40000  0x8e000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140.dll
0x0000000072f30000  0xc000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_1.dll
0x00000000966d0000  0x12a000  C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000097780000  0x12a000  C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
0x000000003ed20000  0x1b000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
0x00000000845a0000  0x1d000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x0000000096a90000  0x73f000  C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x0000000096290000  0x355000  C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x0000000095570000  0x2e000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x0000000096040000  0xcd000   C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x0000000094b00000  0xcc000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x0000000094ac0000  0x3b000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000000007cb30000  0xc000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
0x000000008cd90000  0x108000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll
0x000000007f270000  0x18000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll
0x00000000902e0000  0xa000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x000000008aaf0000  0x27000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000072f00000  0x9000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140_1.dll
0x0000000095030000  0xc000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
0x0000000095530000  0x31000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL
0x0000000094bd0000  0xc000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NETUTILS.DLL
0x0000000087510000  0x28000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SRVCLI.DLL
0x0000000097750000  0x30000   C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000097290000  0x8000    C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
0x00000000930b0000  0x9e000   C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x0000000096950000  0xad000   C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
0x0000000095f10000  0x83000   C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
```

Is anyone familiar with the problem? Please let me know if I can give you any further information for a solution.

Kind regards,
Luca

Answer (score 2):

if you are using anaconda/miniconda with matplotlib installed.
you'll have to install uninstall anaconda/miniconda and use miniconda without matplotlib.

it has be a know issue here [enter link description here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/133862/pyside6-does-not-work-with-anaconda)

Answer (score 0):

Update for all that have the same problem:

What worked for me after all was changing the environment of the QtCreator-project to system environment. The standard selected environment is the build environment.And I spared QtCreator version 6+, with QtCreator5 it's working with that for now. *(The picture is in German version, but I hope you can compare the correct menus)*

So I start my Python-projects in QtCreator 5.15.2 with PySide2. I'm working in a virtual environment of anaconda3 with Python 3.9.7, there I went sure to have installed all PySide and pyqt-related packages (PySide2, PySide6, PyQt5, pyqt5-tools, pyqt, qtpy). All of them with pip3 and --user in addition as there were permissions needed.

Probably that doesn't make sense in every way and some steps here may be trivial, but I myself am still pretty new to the programming world, so maybe someone else can get some value from this info.

**But if someone can explain to me the other problems (build environment not working(only system environment)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0j3I.png), Qt6 not working) I'd be very glad!**