# Why the Interpreter Says "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""..." when a PyQt6 Program Running?

Tags: python, windows, qt, visual-studio-code, pyqt

I'm learning Qt and PyQt, and I think they're useful. I'm trying to use PyQt6 to make a Markdown Editor by VSCode, but the interpreter says:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

But why? When I run a C++ Qt project in Qt Creator, it even has no warning, but when I run a PyQt project, it's error. Because of the editor? But it's error even in Qt Creater!

Code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scr = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(200, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle("My first PyQt5 Project")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(scr.exec_())
```

P.S. Enviroment: WIndows 11 (64-bit), Python 3.10.3, Visual Studio Code, Qt 6, PyQt 5.

Comment: Could you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994485/how-to-fix-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-while-using-m) page?

Answer (score -1):

PyQt6 is not compatible with your machine so I would rather suggest you uninstall it and install PyQt5 using your pip.
So type this on your command line interface:

```
    py -m pip unintall pyqt6
    py -m pip install pyqt5
```

Comment: PyQt6 isn't compatible with Windows 11?

Comment: Please explain why PyQt6 is not compatible with their machine?