# How to fix "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows" running python from boost::python?

Tags: python, qt, boost

I'm running on Windows10. When using Anaconda3 (2021) environment I'm able to execute a simple python script that displays matplotlib figure.

Then, I use the same Anaconda3 environment running the same python script via a C++ APP using the boost::python interface, under the with the Anaconda environment, I get an error "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows".

I've reviewed advice in [How to fix "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows" while using Matplotlib in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994485/how-to-fix-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-while-using-m), but none of the advice helps:

- setting QT_PLUGIN_PATH to point to Anaconda3 plugin platform directory.
- Copying Anaconda3 plugins platform directory content to the same directory as the executable.

How to make Python via boost::python access Anaconda's Qt windows plugin of Anaconda?

Comment: Why would you use boost::python for this instead QProcess to run the python program?

Comment: I have no experience with QProcess, but I think it will not allow me the flexibility of passing data from my C++ to my python script wrapped as boost::python::dict, list etc'

Comment: You will need to add more context. I do not know how boost::python is relevant for running a python script from inside Qt. It sounds like just standard QProcess execution.