# Conda-pack breaks spyder

Tags: python, windows, qt, conda, spyder

I'm trying to use `conda-pack` to distribute a conda env to a different offline machine.

Following the steps at https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/ results in most things working (e.g. python, ipython, importing modules).

However, Spyder is not working.  When I launch spyder from command prompt it says

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or 
load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".
```

I looked into some related discussions like [Qt 5.1.1: Application failed to start because platform plugin "windows" is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495620/qt-5-1-1-application-failed-to-start-because-platform-plugin-windows-is-missi) however I have not found a fix.

Comment: My guess is that conda pack is not running conda post link scripts after unpacking. That's required for Qt to work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a solution to fix the real problem.

I wanted to try to use conda to install to see if I could fix it.

So I used `conda` to clone the broken environment so I could work with this cloned copy of the environment.  For sanity, the first thing I did after cloning the broken environment was to try to run spyder from command prompt. Somewhat surprisingly Spyder worked!

Apparently creating a clone of the environment fixed the problem!

I imagine this might work for other conda users that see the message

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or 
load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".
```

even if they were not using conda-pack.